# Drag & drop vs Touch Events for Angular 2

Tags: angular, events, touch

I need to create a drag & drop functionality to my website. It should work like for example, user can drag the tags (span, div whatever) from the tag list, and drop this tags in contenteditable div.

Do you know how can I do this? I tried to work with hammer.js, and d&d plugins, but the major problem is, that I need drag & drop for desktop (when you can use you mouse), and something using touch events for mobile. Is there any solution/plugin/examples for Angular 2?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this library to be pretty useful for Angular 2 drag and drop.
https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/index.html. I don't know the extent of its mobile capabilities but another option is using Ionic 2 which is a hybrid framework and any libraries compatible with it will have good mobile support.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this :)